# Spinner dropdown covering the whole Screen

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a dialog in my application which contains a spinner. The dialog is designed to cover the full screen space. While the spinner is just a part of the dialog, while selecting dropdown of the spinner, the dropdown covers the whole screen space. Please refer the below image for the dialog reference:

[image]

Now below once clicking the spinner button, the dropdown appears as the below image:

[image]

As you can see, it covers the full screen where as I want its width to be limited to the spinner width. Below I am posting my code for the spinner:

the Dialog code:

```
final Dialog dlg_dialog = new Dialog(myContext, R.style.Theme_Dialog);
                // dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dlg_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                Window window = dlg_dialog.getWindow();
                if (window == null) return;
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                lp.copyFrom(dlg_dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
                lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                dlg_dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_field_quote_entry_dialog);
                dlg_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                dlg_dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                dlg_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_field_quote_entry_dialog);
                //  final Spinner spnr_spinnerSelectMarket = (Spinner)dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectMarket);
                TextView txtv_selectCompetitorDropDown = (TextView) dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectCompetitorDropDown);
                final Spinner spnr_spinnerSelectCompetitor = (Spinner) dlg_dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectCompetitor);
                spnr_spinnerSelectCompetitor.setClickable(false);
                spnr_spinnerSelectCompetitor.setEnabled(false);
```

style.Dialog:

```
 <style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

Now for showing the dropdown, the below code is used:

```
  CustomSpinnerAdapter customSpinnerAdapterCompetitor = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(myContext,
                                    R.layout.spinner_row, alst_competitor, "Select Competitor");
                            competitor_spinner.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapterCompetitor);
```

Now for the CustomSpinnerAdapter:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
ArrayList<String> objects;
String firstElement;
boolean isFirstTime;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects, String defaultText) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.isFirstTime = true;
    setDefaultText(defaultText);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(isFirstTime) {
        objects.set(0, firstElement);
        isFirstTime = false;
    }
    return getCustomDropdownView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
    this.firstElement = objects.get(0);
    objects.set(0,defaultText);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
    TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
    label.setText(objects.get(position));

    return row;
}
public View getCustomDropdownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
    CheckedTextView label = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    label.setText(objects.get(position));


    return row;
}
```

}

If you need any other code references please do let me know. I am unable to resolve this issue. Please do help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use your custom row file instead of default drop down layout file. Custom row file should be wrap_content not match_parent. This will resolve your issue sir.

Comment: Did you try your spinner_row.xml with wrap_content as width. or Please check if the width is not fill_parent

Comment: @VinayakB: yes I tried, but its not helping anyway. The dropdown is still covering the full screen

Comment: android:dropDownWidth="fix your width(100dp)" or programatically setDropDownWidth(desiredWidth); works API level 16 and above

Answer (score 0):

```
/Just remove the below lines of code/

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dlg_dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            dlg_dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: That part is for the dialog, not for the spinner

Comment: @AnimeshJena Buddy if your dialog will appear on full screen then automatically your spinner will cover the whole width. So change the alertdialog width it automatically resolve your spinner issue

Comment: My dialog needs to fill the whole screen where as the spinner drop is not. Thats the requirement. I just want to limit the width of the dropdown to  as of the spinner's width

Comment: @AnimeshJena can you set the drop down using this attribute:
android:dropDownWidth="150dp"

Comment: its not helping either.